# StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer not customizing StreamsBuilderFactoryBean

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have springboot app with Kafka streams where I definitely the main beans as follows.

```
 @Bean
 public StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer streamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer(CustomStateListener customStateListener){
        return factoryBean -> {       
            factoryBean.setStateListener(customStateListener);
        };
 }
    
    
    
@Autowired
public void setStreamsBuilderFactoryBean(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamsBuilderFactoryBean) {
    this.streamsBuilderFactoryBean = streamsBuilderFactoryBean;
    //stateListener is null            

}
```

stateListener  is null, What is missed?

Answer (score 0):

That `StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer` bean is called a bit later, then your `@Autowired` on setter.

Also see docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka.streams.

The `@EnableKafkaStreams` must be present on one of your `@Configuration` class.

Comment: I do have @EnableKafkaStreams in same configuraion class

Comment: Then don't rely on the `@Autowired` to determine the state of the `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean`. As I said before: the customization happens a bit later.